# how to stop multiple IP Address been issued to clients

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, dhcp, centos5

Greeting Guru's

I am using CentOS DHCP and DNS Server.  Recently, I have notice that the DHCP has been issuing multiple IP Address to some clients (Phone/Laptop).  This has caused IP Conflict in the network.

How to Correct this?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: What do you mean `the DHCP has been issuing multiple IP Address to some clients` exactly? Do you mean different ip addresses are being assigned to the same network interface on the same device?

Comment: The DHCP Server is issuing same IP address multiple times to the same client (pc's/laptops etc)

Comment: Can you show us some kind of example of this behavior?